# How to get all contributers in a git history between to branches

Tags: git

I have 2 git branches `old` and `new`. `new` is a few commits ahead of `old`, so a fast forward merge is possible.

How do I list all contributers in the commits from `old` to `new`?

I can list all commits with

```
git log old...new
```

But how can I list only the commiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the committers along their commits use `git shortlog`, if you just want to see who's committed and how many times, no details use `git shortlog -sn`.

Comment: `git log` also has the `--pretty` option: `git log --pretty=format:"a%N" old..new` but it is not as pretty as the answer